# $.extend copy attributes of functional constructor

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, lodash

We use functional constructors(Douglas Crockford's functional inheritance pattern ) and copy only the attributes to validate them. The code is like this.

```
    var test= function(TestSpec){
        var thattest = {};

        thattest.begindate = TestSpec.begindate;
        thattest.getBegindate = function(){
            return thattest.begindate;
        };

        return  thattest;
    }
```

//This is what I tried initially to copy the attributes

```
        var copy = $.extend(true, {}, test )
        console.log(copy);
        _.each(copy, function(c) {
            console.log('[' + c + ']');
        });
```

How do I copy only the attributes ? I am looking for a way to use a functional style to copy the attributes to another object.
We can use underscore.js or lodash if needed.

Comment: Define "attributes." Do you mean properties that don't refer to functions?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. In particular, `$.extend(true, {}, test)` doesn't look particularly meaningful.

Comment: I asked it a few minutes back :-) We copy only attributes and not functions. The code is repeated everywhere and we have many functional constructors.

Comment: @Roamer I was trying to use JQuery since I was looking for a succint way to do it. I also want to try a functional style using underscore or lodash.

Comment: Still not clear. What do you mean by "functional constructors" and what are you trying to do with/to them?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to copy only properties that don't refer to functions, then it's fairly simple using a recursive function of your own:

```
function copyAttributes(src) {
    var dest = {};
    Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) {
        var value = src[key];
        switch (typeof value) {
            case "function":
                break;
            case "object":
                dest[key] = copyAttributes(value);
                break;
            default:
                dest[key] = value;
                break;
        }
    });
    return dest;
}
```

Usage:

```
var copy = copyAttributes(test);
```

You might want to do something more intelligent in the `"object"` case above for cloning built-in types (arrays, `Date`, `RegExp`, etc.). You might `switch` on [`jQuery.type(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/), which gives you more information to work with.

Comment: What about the powerful underscore.js or lodash ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan: Well, do you see something in the API docs that does it?

Comment: console.log( _.functions(object)); 
I think I could exclude functions using this. But console.log( _.functions(test)); does not work.